# .NET Regular Expressions - Shorter match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a question regarding .NET regular expressions and how it defines matches.
I am writing:

```
var regex = new Regex("<tr><td>1</td><td>(.+)</td><td>(.+)</td>");
if (regex.IsMatch(str))
{
    var groups = regex.Match(str).Groups;
    var matches = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < groups.Count; i++)
        matches.Add(groups[i].Value);

    return matches;
}
```

What I want is get the content of the two following  tags. Instead it returns:

> ```
> [0]: Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td>...
> [1]: Last row of the table
> ```

Why is the first match taking </td> and the rest of the string instead of stopping at </td>?

Comment: BTW, obligatory warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression includes

```
(.+)
```

which is a *greedy* match. Greedy matches extend as *far* as they can before matching the next character (`<` in your case). Try:

```
(.+?)
```

This is a *non-greedy* match which extends as *little* as possible before matching the next character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify lazy matching.  Instead of `+`, use `+?` to say that as few chars as possible should match.